# How to read a Structured_Points .vtk file

Tags: opengl-es, vtk

I currently have CT image data of a human head. It contains 256 slices in the YZ plane, 256 slices in the XZ plane, and 144 slices in the XY plane.

I'm planning to use OpenGL-ES 3.0 on Android to plot the points of one slice in the XY Plane. The problem is, I'm unsure of how to load the ASCII data below into arrays and buffers. I've included a small snippet of the file.

```
# vtk DataFile Version 4.0
vtk output
ASCII
DATASET STRUCTURED_POINTS
DIMENSIONS 256 256 144
SPACING 1 1 1
ORIGIN 0 0 0
POINT_DATA 9437184
SCALARS ImageFile unsigned_short
LOOKUP_TABLE default
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

How do I make sense of the data given in the lookup table?

**EDIT:** I understand how to view the data in programs such as Paraview. I would like to understand what the data is actually telling me, so I can create a custom parser and use OpenGL-ES to draw the 2D slices myself.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to just load in the data into VTK using the vtkDataReader? As I understand it, as  Structured Points data is a subclass of vtkImageData you should be able to do something as simple as the following using vtk in Python.

```
import vtk
from vtk.util import numpy_support

path = 'path_to_file.vtk'

reader = vtk.vtkDataReader()
reader.SetFileName(path)

img = vtk.vtkImageData()
array = numpy_support.vtk_to_numpy(img)

#z_plane of choice
z = 10
plane = array[:,:,10]
```

Similiar code will also work if it's in C++ I just by using the GetScalarPointer or GetScalarComponentAsDouble functions and looping over the plane of choice given you know the dimensions from GetDimensions() and building a vtkImageData or by using the vtkImageReslice function and passing an approriate transform

Comment: I understand how to view the data, using software such as Paraview. My problem is that I would like to create a custom parser in Java. I want to read each number and store it an arrays, and then draw the slices using OpenGL-ES. The problem is, I don't understand what the structured points are telling me.